# How to group Cloud Function log entries by execution?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

In Google App Engine, first generation, logs are grouped automatically by request in Logs Viewer, and in the second generation [it's easy enough to set up](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/usage.html#integration-with-python-logging-module).

In *background* Cloud Functions I can't find any way of doing it (save manually filtering by `executionId` in Logs Viewer). From various articles around the web I read that the key is to set the `trace` argument  to the Trace ID when calling the Stackdriver Logging API, and that in *HTTP contexts* this ID can be found in the `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` header.

There are no headers in background contexts (for example, called from Pub/Sub or Storage triggers). I've tried setting this to an arbitrary value, such as the `event_id` from the function context, but no grouping happens.

Here's a minified representation of how I've tried it:

```py
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource
import google.cloud.logging

log_name = 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions'
cloud_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
cloud_logger = cloud_client.logger(log_name)

request_id = None


def log(message):
    labels = {
        'project_id': 'settle-leif',
        'function_name': 'group-logs',
        'region': 'europe-west1',
    }
    resource = Resource(type='cloud_function', labels=labels)
    trace_id = f'projects/settle-leif/traces/{request_id}'
    cloud_logger.log_text(message, trace=trace_id, resource=resource)


def main(_data, context):
    global request_id
    request_id = context.event_id

    log('First message')
    log('Second message')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is currently possible.

It's on our roadmap to provide this support: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/issues/79

Comment: That's great. Thank you!

Comment: This is on our roadmap, see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/issues/79